# RFID reader for a keyless residential entry system?

Tags: rfid

What are some good RFID readers to look at for a keyless residential entry system? Are there any on the market that can read a key fob or similar RFID token from a range of 3 feet or more?  This would be a DIY project for a new home, so price is less of an issue than reliability and ease of integration.

Comment: Beware that RFID sniffer in someone's pocket passing by at 3 feet could also read ID from your card and use it to identify as your self in front of your own house. Smart cards are much safer option. On the other side, a real burglar will just try to override electrical lock opening command voltage, so additional in house alarm is always recommended.

Comment: @avra: Is there such a thing as an RFID smart-card?

Comment: Google for "rfid" "cryptographic" "protocol" and you will see. Just remember that RFID sniffer can act as any RFID reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some more Googling on this topic (armed with some hints provided by Kellenjb, tronixstuff and avra), I have turned up an example of the kind of reader I'm interested in:
[Home Automation RFID Reader](http://www.iautomate.com/products/Home-Automation-RFID-Reader.html)

I will be trying to find a tear-down of this or a similar unit that describes the components it uses. I'll try to keep this answer updated with what I learn.

Answer (score 4):

Sparkfun has some RFID devices that are fairly DIY ready. Here is a link to one:
http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8419

This is if you are wanting to actually build your own device to do keyless entry. If you are wanting a pre-built key-less entry you might need to look else where.

**EDIT:**
After answering I did realize you mentioned that you wanted reliability and ease of integration. My solution probably isn't the best for this requirement.
Look at this site: http://www.househacker.com/permanent/DIY-RFID-Access-to-your-Front-Door

Comment: Kellenjb, I'd seen some references to the Sparkfun offerings before, but the link has a nice video showing some real-world range tests with the devices they sell. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Mark Booth I removed the link for you, although I think the bigger issue with LMGTFY is when it is the entire answer. But this was a long time ago when I was still somewhat new to the SE point of view.

Comment: @Kellenjb - Thanks, converted to a +1. I got stung with a lmgtfy links early in my time on SO, and it convinced me that even in jest, there's no place for it as it seems to offend people mightily.

Comment: I have a rfid reader in a 12-key keyboard. It'll will work for access, but is useless for any real security, as all the electronics is in the same unit. It's just "unscrew the keybord and connect red and green wires"-movie style.

Answer (score 2):

Jon Oxer (the co-author of "Practical Arduino") has documented home-access RFID systems on his [website](http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/rfid-access-control-system). He is also the first Australian to have an RFID implant.

Comment: I mean this as a user, your post is lacking anything technical. This guys is great, here is another reason, now go to his website.